# How to prove positive definiteness?

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

$B_{(n+1)(n+1)}$ = $       \begin{bmatrix}
        A & u \\
        u^T & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$

is given, and $A$ is a positive definite matrix where its Cholesky factorization is given by $A=L*L^T$ formula. $A$ is $n\times n$ matrix and $u$ is a n_vector.

Now assuming $\|L\|^{-1}\leq 1$, I need to show that $B$ is a positive definite for all $\|u\|<1$.

Thanks

Comment: The Schur Complement [condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement#Schur_complement_condition_for_positive_definiteness) for positive definiteness is useful here.

Comment: What is $\lVert L\rVert$?

Comment: Can you maybe provide more detailed solution?

Comment: @Davide that is a norm of matrix L

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the Schur complement [condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement#Schur_complement_condition_for_positive_definiteness) for positive definiteness, $B$ is positive definite iff $A$ is positive definite and $1 - u^T A^{-1} u > 0$.  Now,
\begin{align*}
|u^T A^{-1} u | &\leq \| u \| \| A^{-1} u \| \quad \text{(by Cauchy Schwarts)} \\
&\leq \|u\| \|L^{-T}\| \|L^{-1}\| \|u\| \\
&< 1.
\end{align*}
(In the last step, I use $\|u\| < 1$ and $\| L^{-1} || = \|L^{-T} \| \leq 1$.)

This shows that $1 - u^T A^{-1} u > 0$, so $B > 0$.

Comment: I don't know about that Schur complement condition, but something is wrong. Consider the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1/2&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$; this is not positive definite, but it would be according to your condition.

Comment: @all:  I made a mistake it should be $\|L\|^{-1}\leq 1$

Comment: Thanks, I think I fixed the answer now.

Comment: Now if I try to do Cholesky factorization of B, given that the complexity of $A=L*L^T$ is N, will B's complexity be $N+4n^2$?

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that $\|L\|$ refers to the operator norm, and that $\|u\|$ refers to the Frobenius norm.

The way the question is phrased, it is not true that $B$ is positive definite. Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1/2\end{bmatrix}$, $u=\begin{bmatrix}0\\3/4\end{bmatrix}$. Then $L=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1/\sqrt2\end{bmatrix}$, and 
$$
B=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1/2&3/4\\0&3/4&1\end{bmatrix}
$$
is not positive definite, as
$$
\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\-1/2\end{bmatrix}^TB\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\-1/2\end{bmatrix}=-\frac18
$$